# Custom role: adding a new node results page not directing properly

Tags: users

- Current roles I have:
- ...., authenticated user, student, staff, admin, ...
- I create a new content type and only staff & site admin (i.e. I only check permission for staff & site admin. Other roles don't have any permission checks)can do something to it.
- I login as a staff and try to add a node. The "add node page" for new content type cannot be accessed (too much redirects in chrome, then die)
- If I select "authenticated user" things start working, but other roles are selected as well.
- Build-in roles like editor, site admin have no issues. It seems the issues are caused by custom role.
- I used module content access, not sure that causes issues. I disabled it, still no luck.
- Any idea?

**Update:** Staff has not been assigned with "staff role" uuuuuhhhh

Comment: Did you rebuild permissions after changing the permissions for staff & site admin? Usually it will work normally. By the way. Do you use one of Rules, Triggers, Context, HTTPs or just the basic modules.

Comment: Rebuild the permissions doesn't work. I have rules for example installed, but I don't think we use it. (Need to check)